# Listbox and mysql value

Tags: php, mysql, listboxitem

I want to use "Listbox and mysql value" script one of my projects. I have tables called Districts (40 Districts with `districtid` and `districtname`) & Cities (100 cities with `cityid`, `cityname` and `districtid`) and another table stores the house owner names and located district and city (this tables store the `districtid` value and `cityid`).

I have a php page, through that owners can change or edit their district or city anytime. In this page, I want to display the owners district and the city in listboxes and selected values should be displays corresponding to house owners data table. How can I use your code for this?

Comment: do you mean drop-down-box, and do you want the values to update (narrow down) as parent is selected

Answer (score 1):

If i understand you question well, it's just about the logic:

1. get owner city and district
2. get districts, while looping through them to present then, check id with owner distruct id, if they match, set option to selected.
3. same for city.